# dictionary application with suggest by c# and sqlite search fulltext so slow

Tags: c#, sqlite, dictionary, full-text-search

I'm writing a dictionary application by C# and SQLite DB.
When i edit the search textbox it will list the similar word in a listbox. It can work but speed so slow, running performance so slow.
Should i use a thread or use better algorithm. I was created index in my DB, this table have 100.000 records.
How to make the performance better? please help me. Thanks!

listSuggest is a ListBox.

```
private void txtKeyword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectString);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "select word from mytable where word like '" + txtKeyword.Text + "%' or search like '" + txtKeyword.Text + "%' order by id asc limit 0,200";
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn);
            SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                listSuggest.Items.Add(reader["word"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also use `using` statement to dispose your connection, command and reader automatically.

Comment: You could do searching in another thread (Task) but if table is small, you could just read all at startup and search in memory.

Comment: _How to make the performance better?_ would be better in [CodeReview.SE] maybe?

Comment: If the data is static, you can cache the select results and lookup from the cache afterwards.

Comment: Show the table and index definitions.